# Create a report in both Portrait and in Landscape mode

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to create a template in *iReport* where the first page is in landscape mode and the second page is in portrait mode. However I achieve this by having two templates and calling them one by one, after creating two jasper Prints which would generate two pdfs, but my clients prefer having one pdf with two pages.

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint1);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint2);
```

Comment: You should add two subreport for this. first one in portrait mode and second one in landscape mode.

Comment: Tried that, to achieve that I tried creating a summary band and in properties I chose to show summary as a separate page and set my sub-report in summary, but when setting the size of the sub-report in my main report it goes out of bounds i.e., when I set it to a landscape, the sub-report generates error saying invalid position.

Comment: Post your jrxml code.